# AJAX .load url and postback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, postback

I am bringing in a particular div (.source_div) from one part of my website into another div (.destination_div) on another part of my website using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.destination_div').load('http://myurl.mypage.com/something.aspx .source_div');
});
</script>
```

However, the .source_div contains links that go to other parts of my website. When I click on these links, I would like for those pages to continue displaying within my same .destination_div that I am on, and not taking me away to another page (which is what it currently does). On another slightly related note, I also have a form within my .source_div that that performs a postback which also appends the html. This does not work within my .load either. I have looked around and cannot figure out how to do either one of these things correctly. Could someone please help with one or both of these issues?

Comment: Then make sure your links do not contain hard-coded domains [e.g. `href="http://somedomain.com/somepage.aspx"`] in them and no `target="_blank"` attributes.

Comment: all of my URLs will have to look something like this: http://myurl.mypage.com/something.aspx?pageID=12345 and the only thing that changes between them is the pageID at the end

Comment: Okay anyways, I think you were saying, your AJAX requests failed, thus on click the content takes over the entire page completely. Am I right?

Comment: correct. the links that are contained in my .source_div take me out to those pages, instead of updating .destination_div with that new content. I will also add here that all of the pages on my site have a .source_div named exactly the same way.

Comment: Right, then implement the solution of Kevin B. below. Bind all your links to a click event that does the same thing in your code above.

Comment: Is answer #1 from this post sort of what you are talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304299/jquery-load-content-from-link-with-ajax

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same thing, different code but same effect.

Comment: alright. this code looks good. however, how do I load the initial div into the page? the code that you gave me listens for clicks and updates the loaded div that displays, but how do I also incorporate the original div that should display when the page loads for the first time? The code I used above accomplished this, what is the best way to combine them?

Comment: just add your previous code [the load() part only] before the click() handler (see updated answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation could be something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.destination_div').load('http://myurl.mypage.com/something.aspx .source_div'); // your page is loaded first
   $('.destination_div').on('click','a',function() {
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.destination_div').load(url);
       return false;
   });
});​
```

EDIT: added your previous code

Answer (score 0):

Delegate an event to all anchor tags within the `destination_div` element that performs the same `.load`, just with the href of the given link.

http://api.jquery.com/on
http://api.jquery.com/delegate