# Opening div over div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have divided my page into 2 halves. Now I have few links in my left sidebar.I want to call the content of the links on my right sidebar without loading my page again.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 sidebarleft">
                <br>
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#div1">BookMarks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#div2">Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#div3">Desk Organiser</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 sidebarright">
                <div class="div2">

                </div>
                <div class="div3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show some of your Style and make a fiddle.

Comment: *"I want to call the content of the links on my right sidebar"* -- What? I see no links on the right sidebar. Also, what do you mean "call" the content of the links? You should look into ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery load content from link with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304299/jquery-load-content-from-link-with-ajax)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ms6g1vt/

Comment: ok Casey I will look into Ajax. But for can any1 suggest me a way to overide div over each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to look into is Ajax. This can be achieved in multiple ways, but one of the most common methods is with [Ajax in Jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Jquery has a [nice wrapper function load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), this should do everything that you need.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $(".div2").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note, you will need to ensure that the href="" bits in the link list point to valid URLs

Comment: No problems Tanuj. Good luck in your journey.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use either Frames, IFrames, or AJAX.

- [Frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) - Not in HTML5 so not a good option.
- [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) - Forward Compatible but clunky.
- [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) - Probably your best bet but not for the faint of heart.