# AdminLTE - Loading different content for each menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, lte

I'm using AdminLTE to build my Admin page, and i'm trying to understand how to load (with jquery) different snippets of code for each link i click to.

For example: in the sidebar menu i have 1, 2, 3, 4. When i link on 1, a snippet appears in the content div, and the same is for the others...

Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is your friend!

Attach the handle to a link with an click event and it will work. The examples on the jQuery-page are pretty straightforward.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304299/jquery-load-content-from-link-with-ajax) question on stackoverflow.